# database design for social network

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm designing a database for social media which is similar to facebook structure. I'm using MySQL. The main goal for our database is the performance, it must handle a high number of requests.

I have a list of users, friends, posts on wall, comments and likes.

Q1- for users, I have several types of users, I have normal users, supervisors and admin. for that table, I'm thinking to define one parent user table and then inherit the information, but at the same time the fields are same. 
example:

```
user
=============
id
username
password
email
isAtcive
country

noraml_user
===============
name
..
..
user_id

supervisor
==============
name
..
..
user_id

admin
=======
name
..
..
user_id
```

I considered this method because of performance, so instead of searching for single user using user type in (one million users as an example), I search for (300K users in table supervisor). Am I right?

Q2- I have likes for the posts and comments. here is my design

```
posts
==========
id
content

comments
==========
id
content
post_id

posts_likes
==========
id
post_id
user_id

comment_likes
==========
id
comment_id
user_id
```

Do you think this is correct, or I just make one table for likes such as the following

```
likes
=========
id
post_id(nullable)
comment_id(nullable)
user_id
```

what is best approach?

Q3- Could you provide me some tips to be considered for designing social network database?

Thanks :)

Comment: I would put the differents of users (admin etc.) in the users table and just make an extra column. 0 = normal, 1=super etc.

Comment: If you're going with permissions, I would suggest adding another table user_groups and give each user a group_id. Also, read up on working with bit masks for efficiency as there is really no need to have a supervisor column over a bitmask that can hold that value plus 31 others.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: You shouldn't create separate tables for different user types. In fact, you should have a user role column in a common user table. This role would then define what the user can do. The whole point of indexes is to efficiently find subsets of a table.

Q2: Again, you'll probably find that you have content and likes (or maybe even "reactions"). Unless there's a specific reason to keep posts special, they're really just content that has no parent.

Q3: Yeah, so that's way to o broad a question for a site like this.